# Codeigniter real_escape_string function can't call

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added the line below from my models

```
$this->db->close();
```

And then this code gives me an error

```
Severity: error --> Exception: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on boolean
```

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Here are the configs I use. Main DB connection

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'is my host address',
    'username' => 'is my id',
    'password' => 'is my password',
    'database' => 'is my database name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => APPPATH.'cache/db/',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: if connection close is not necessary then don't close database connection.

Comment: Can you query anything against $this->db?

Comment: @Bhavin I have added `$this->db->close()` because there are too many sleep process which is caused by not disconnecting after desired job is done and I want to make sure all the connections are closed after they are done.

Comment: @Antony Yes. Of course. I only added the code where `$this->db` has some result to return

Comment: My guess is you are running a db operation after using db->close().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DBdriver is mysqli so you have to use real_escape_string() because its belong from mysql dbdriver

You can use $this->db->escape_str() or $this->db->escape() function of codeigniter