# An ERROR shows "This page isn’t working, localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I currently taking over someone project. This project uses codeigniter 3.
When I run the site localhost/proj, it works just fine. But when try to login to the admin site localhost/proj/admin/login. It shows HTTP ERROR 500, This page isn’t working, localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

Someone suggest me to look into the Apache(error.log). It shows "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function real_escape_string() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php on line 391".

I read that it might be my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #--- Uncomment this line for production or testing server
    #SetEnv CI_ENV production

    #--- URL rewrite
    #--- Note: require Rewrite mod enabled (sudo a2enmod rewrite)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Reference: https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me with this? please.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542320/codeigniter-real-escape-string-function-cant-call

Comment: it apparently means that your script is unable to connect to database

Answer (score -1):

yes i had the same issue with my app, but when i removed the htaccess, the app started working fine